# Not able to upload tar.gz file using Python Request Module

Tags: python, python-requests

Here is what my XHR data looks like when captured in chrome

**Request Header**

```
POST my_url?X-Progress-ID=ee821652321919bc7ae61fbe0b625990&userpkgname=file_name.tar.gz HTTP/1.1
Host: 10.110.134.28
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 17461
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: https://10.110.134.28
X-XSRF-TOKEN: bGIwdfFE-oaL_1yVrCzw0iHvv4yUHLC28xjw
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarybfK9jSdLoc2Mpj0i
Referer: https://10.110.134.28/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=bGIwdfFE-oaL_1yVrCzw0iHvv4yUHLC28xjw; sid=s%3AXglfJNLQ9zzp3eHjQ2QOpk19kFKDDMvJ.ZMKyZd1Gx13lz2MnJgty5WncnilySzfoThGktkhlk4w
```

**Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundarybfK9jSdLoc2Mpj0i
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="package"; filename="file_name.tar.gz"
Content-Type: application/x-gzip


------WebKitFormBoundarybfK9jSdLoc2Mpj0i--
```

And this is how I am building my request.

```
files = {'package': (<file_name>, open(config_path, 'rb'), 'application/x-gzip')}
request.post(url, files=files)
```

This is how my **request header** looks like

```
{
    'Content-Length' : '17449',
    'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept' : '*/*',
    'User-Agent' : 'python-requests/2.10.0',
    'Connection' : 'keep-alive',
    'Cookie' : 'XSRF-TOKEN=zmklLEL0-gDJOfNBk113MuTpBkLo0j6MAzw0; sid=s%3AC2JZDCfpg_CgkU7qSlS5YTvWXwpgMX35.5nU7W02TPNYtMkIQ4W%2B1bjd87A7KyJbh3shoNqqADXE',
    'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data; boundary=270d9e02bf214dc7a09c3081cba5b0e0',
    'XSRF-TOKEN' : 'zmklLEL0-gDJOfNBk113MuTpBkLo0j6MAzw0'
}
```

When I make the request I get `502 bad gateway` response that too after few seconds while on chrome I get `200 OK` instantly

So most probably I am not building my request correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try matching all of the headers? In your request it's `XSRF-TOKEN`, in the original one there's  `X-XSRF-TOKEN`. `Origin` is missing, so is `Referer`.

Comment: That dint help :(

Comment: Can you share the url? I thinkk you may need to do a get to the page first to set the cookies etc.. then do your post.